# Microsoft Equation subscript not working as normal

Tags: microsoft-word, equations, equation-editor

So I've been using Microsoft Equation Editor for the past 3 months or so, and all of a sudden I'm getting a different result when I want a subscript. For example, if I want to get *D<sub>min</sub>*, I type "D_min".
Previously I got this result:
[image: D_min_correct]

But now when I type that, I get the following:
[image: D_min_incorrect]

If I want to get it to show up the correct way, I have to force it to "professional" view.
How can I make this go back to working the way it did?

Comment: if you click on the blue links it will show a picture. I'm not sure why it doesn't display it in the post...

Comment: ahhh.... that was it! I never deleted it out of a list, but now that it is deleted, I am not have the issue any more. Thanks for the response!! If you want to create an answer that says that, I will accept it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with whether or not `min` is listed as a "recognised function".

You get the first behavior you list (where `min` is subscripted) if it is *not* listed as a function.

You get the second behaviour if `min` *is* listed as a recognised function. I believe min is listed by default.

Perhaps `min` has been "re-listed" as a result of an update or an Office repair.

A button in the Math Autocorrect dialog box leads to a further dialog where you can maintain this list.